# Disable Landscape for Split View Controller for iPhone in Universal App

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, ipad

I have a universal app with a `UISplitViewController`. I want the iPad version to work in both portrait and landscape but I only want the app to work in portrait on iPhone. I tried using the following on my Main View Controller and it did not work:

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return false
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
}
```

I think the problem is that the split view controller overrides the these two methods. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure it out by setting the supported app interface orientations at launch in the `AppDelegate`:

```
let deviceIdiom = UIScreen.mainScreen().traitCollection.userInterfaceIdiom

func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if deviceIdiom == .Pad {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i think this is what you looking for

```
  [splitViewController setHidesMasterViewInPortrait:NO];
```

Comment: I want to just disable landscape all together though

Comment: I'm not seeing this property on UISplitViewController anymore.